# Can you easily debug your code again while the last debugger/console still is open? (Visual studio 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way/option to always press f5 to "re-run" your code with the console after you've made some changes to it. As for now, you have to close the console/debugger and run again to start your program instead of just pressing f5 to close old console and run the new one.

In the IDLE environment, you could do that and I kind of miss it since it made coding/programming a little faster.

Edit: To clarify, I do some changes, save the code and press f5. But the old console is still running. Which means I have to close it first.

Comment: After you made the changes - the code needs to be recompiled. Simply closing, and re-running wouldn't run your modified code.

Comment: you can do the same by `ctrl + shift + F5`

Comment: Change the settings as per your convienient in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. for restart debugging select Debug.Restart and assign a shortcut key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest we could try to click the Restart button in the Debug Toolbar (Ctrl + Shift + F5). When you press Restart, it saves time versus stopping the app and restarting the debugger.

[image]